# While I agree that this starts as a rant

Tags: discussion

Why is this question deleted?
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10903/a-junior-employee-is-being-promoted-to-my-manager-possible-counters

I think it is a valid question that needs to be here and could be good question with closing and a little rewrite. There are many people who don't know what todo when they have to work for someone that used to be junior to them and whose skils they may nto respect.

Comment: I agree the op had just given the piece of information that was needed to pull that question together...

Comment: @HLGEM i'm going to point out that your "repost" doesn't quite seem to match up to the original.  OP in the original didn't give indication (unless he edited it after i last saw the question) of him seeking the promotion.  It was more that he was upset that the one getting the promotion was less experienced.  OP was not "in competition for [the] promotion".

Comment: You can change it, if you think it needs it . I made that assumnmption since he specifically mentions office plitics which are usually not as much a conern if you aren't trying to get promoted.

Comment: I thought he also explicitly said he did not play politics and such, implying that he wasn't jockeying for the position.  regardless, the question as you worded it is a very good one, so i don't think we should make any real changes unless original OP requests.

Answer (score 4):

The question was deleted by the owner.

Comment: Too bad, it had the germ of a nice question in it.

Comment: @HLGEM If you want to make an edit to increase the quality, perhaps you can change Quinma's mind about deletion.

Answer (score 4):

I added a question based on what I wanted to answer, but if anyone esle would like to take a shot at improving it, feel free.  Jim if you agree my question is a good one, can you transfer it to Quinma? I didn't realize I could edit a closed question. And I don't need or want the rep.

[My new boss was junior to me, what do I do?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10904/my-new-boss-was-junior-to-me-what-do-i-do)

Comment: I wanted to say great job on writing that question. Most posts written by third parties have that third-party feel to them, but your use of the first person makes it look genuine!

Answer (score 3):

I voted to close because of [exactly what I wrote here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1774/2322).

I also did not downvote, because of what you say (it was interesting at core, just really rant-ish).

---

Specifically this step

1. Downvote or vote to close poor questions *immediately* - do NOT say, "well there's a good question here, so I'll leave it open to be edited." Leaving poor questions open encourages answers - which normally match the quality of the question.

Comment: I don't see anything software-localized about that question.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @NickC sorry I was referring to what I edited in.