# questions based on bad or wrong assumptions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-evaluation

Sometimes there are questions that are based on very bad or wrong assumptions. I am thinking of something like [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/153424/what-is-a-reasonable-number-of-lines-of-code-that-developers-should-commit-per-d), that is 'how many lines of codes should a programmer commit per day?'. The top answer says you shouldn't measure productivity by lines of code and explains why and I completely agree with it. But the original question currently has an overall score of -4 and I assume it is at risk of being closed as a bad question.

My question: does this count as a bad question? To me it seems like a good question and hopefully the answer is actually useful to OP. OP has some misunderstandings but OP asked a question about it and we are trying to help. Looks all good to me.

So should questions like this be encouraged or not?

Comment: "So should questions like this be encouraged or not?" - that's what votes are for. If you want to "encourage" the question, vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there's nothing wrong with the question, that the question's proposed method is incorrect is merely an opportunity for answerers to explain that and give better answers.

Most if not all professional coders will be able to point out the extreme poorness of using such a metric but to a non-coder such as the OP it's not obvious, and if a good answer can persuade the OP of this and give them a better way of measuring coder performance then we can not only help a manager get better at managing coders but also give whoever they manage a better working environment, sounds like a win-win to me.